# Power BI-DAX Permutation and filtering - How?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables, 1 table contains numbers of 4 digits, say 1234.

Another table contains the permutation results of 1234, say 4321,2314,3124,4213 and so on.

I would like to perform a filtering on my visual, say if I select 1234 on a filtering slicer, options for the permutation will made available for me to select also, so that I can select 1234,4321,2314,3124 and other permutations as a selected filtering and use it on a bar chart with counting frequency, any other alternative ways can be suggested too.

Tried with multiple dax answers from chatgpt and none of them works!